# Restructurar los datos dentro de una lista en Python

Tags: python, lista, agrupación

Hola amigos: tengo la siguiente lista con esta información:

```
lista= [0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 2]
```

pero necesito que los datos dentro de ella queden acomodados por pares y dentro de las comillas; de esta manera: (tiene que ser una lista preferiblemente)

```
lista= ["0:2”,”1:0","1:1","1:2","2:1","2:2",”3:1”,”3:2”,”4:1”,”4:2”]
```

Díganme que si es posible y que proceso puedo realizar, agradezco la colaboración. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar comprensión de listas, `slices` y `zip()`

Para obtener todos los elementos en las posiciones par (0,2,4,6, ...)

```
lista[::2]
```

Para obtener todos los elementos en las posiciones non (1,3,5,7, ...)

```
lista[1::2]
```

Para generar el par de datos utilizamos zip

```
zip(lista[::2], lista[1::2])
```

Para obtener la lista resultante utilizamos comprensión de listas

```
[str(i) + ':' + str(j) for i,j in zip(lista[::2], lista[1::2])]
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
lista = [0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 2]

resultado = [str(i) + ':' + str(j) for i,j in zip(lista[::2], lista[1::2])]

print(resultado)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
['0:2', '1:0', '1:1', '1:2', '2:1', '2:2', '3:1', '3:2', '4:1', '4:2']
```

Comment: Gracias, con una lista de 72 elementos nos funciona. ¿Existe algún tope de longitud? debo trabajar con listas extensas.

Comment: No existen limitaciones, lo único que debes tener en cuenta es que si la longitud de la lista no es par no funcionará correctamente. Recuerda que parte de la cultura de Stack Overflow es que los usuarios hagan un esfuerzo por resolver sus propias dudas, te sugiero que hagas bastantes pruebas y que leas los conceptos relacionados a la respuesta, no que solo copies y pegues el código

Comment: @JulianAicardy, Si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas

Comment: Gracias nuevamente. podía reunir todas las listas en una sola y lo hice. 3578 elementos y lo hizo perfectamente. me quedó la duda porque con la de 72 no jejejeje

Comment: Lo probé con 72 valores y funciona bien, ¿Sería posible que tus datos de la lista de 72 elementos están mal?

Comment: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Podría recorrer solo los indices pares y agregar a una nueva lista los valores formateados de esta manera **"valorActual:ValorSiguiente"**

```
lista = [0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 2]

nueva_lista = []

i = 0
while i < len(lista):
    nueva_lista.append(str(lista[i]) + ":" + str(lista[i + 1]))
    i += 2

print(nueva_lista)
```

Ojo: Solo funciona si tu lista tiene como longitud un numero par.

Comment: Gracias, al hacerlo en una lista de 72 elementos, no funciona =(

Answer (score 0):

Con una comprensión de listas:

```
resultado = [f"{lista[i]}:{lista[i+1]}" for i in range(0, len(lista), 2)]
```

**Demo**

```
lista= [0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 2]

print([f"{lista[i]}:{lista[i+1]}" for i in range(0, len(lista), 2)])
```

produce:

```
['0:2', '1:0', '1:1', '1:2', '2:1', '2:2', '3:1', '3:2', '4:1', '4:2']

Process finished with exit code 0
```